# Draw interactive polyline in UIView (Core Graphics? OpenGL?)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, opengl-es, uikit, core-graphics

For an iOS project, I'm trying to rend a polyline over a UIImageView that is interactive in real time. That is, the user can touch a handle at any point on the line and drag it to reshape it.

I'm able to draw the line in Core Graphics, when I try to drag it, the gesture recognizer calls `setNeedsDisplay` so many frequently that it causes memory warning and crashes. Xcode tell me Xcode says "Terminated due to memory pressure."

I'm drawing the line like this, but with a for loop for multiple segments. However it seems that the contents of `drawRect` aren't the problem. Even if I comment the contents all out, frequently calling `setNeedsDisplay` drastically affects the performance.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 6.0);
    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, pointA.x, pointA.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, pointB.x, pointB.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

I've looked around and I'm only seeing tutorials for doing this in map kit. There must be some way to get this done. Perhaps Core Graphics isn't the best approach?

EDIT: The UIImageView is a high-resolution image (taken from the iPhone camera), in a UIScrollView. I'm guessing that calling `setNeedsDisplay` for a view of that size takes a lot of resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The problem was this it was calling `setNeedsDisplay` too frequently on a very large UIView. Apple recommends keeping them as small as possible, though they're no longer limited to a certain size. Resizing the image before drawing on it should remove any memory warnings.

Found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Answer (score 0):

The drawing code is fine.  There is an inherent delay and overhead in using gesture recognisers that I think is causing your problems (in my opinion). You should be implementing the -(void)touches... Events instead (there are four of them)

Comment: I tried playing around with that, and it seems that the problem is the opposite. That is, in a short pan gesture, the gesture recognizer could be calling `setNeedsDisplay` more than 40 times in a single second. Perhaps it's due to the size of the UIView, but that's what seems to be causing the memory to spike over 300MB. Any ideas other ideas @Jef?